# Display nested object from collection in nested itemrepeater ASP.NET 4

Tags: c#, asp.net

My Cart class

```
public class Cart
{
    [Key]
    public int CartID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int BillID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [ForeignKey("BillID")]
    public virtual Bill Bill { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<CartItems> Products {get; set;}
}
```

My CartItems class

```
public class CartItems
    {
        [Key]
        public int CartItemID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int ProductId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("ProductId")]
        public Product Product { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int Qunatity { get; set; }
    }
```

My query for populating the inner repeater looks like this:

```
List<AdminCartItems> items = (from c in context.Carts
                                              where c.Bill.Date == currentDate
                                              select new AdminCartItems
                                              {
                                                  Products = c.Products,
                                                  BillNo = c.Bill.BillNumber,
                                                  Orderer = c.Bill.Name + ", " + c.Bill.Adress + ", " + c.Bill.PostalCode + " " + c.Bill.Country,
                                                  Sum = c.Products.Sum(x => x.Qunatity * x.Product.Price)
                                              }).ToList();

            CartRepeater.DataSource = items;
            this.DataBind();

public class AdminCartItems
    {
        public ICollection<CartItems> Products {get; set;}
        public int BillNo {get; set;}
        public string Orderer {get; set; }
        public double Sum {get; set;}
    }
```

The aspx page looks like this:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="CartRepeater" runat="server"> 
    <ItemTemplate>
        <p><b>Broj računa: </b><%# Eval("BillNo")%></p>
        <p><b>Naručioc: </b><%# Eval("Orderer")%></p>
        <br />

        <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th><center><b>Slika</b></center></th>
            <th><center><b>Proizvod</b></center></th>
            <th><center><b>Količina</b></center></th>
            <th><center><b>Cena</b></center></th>
            <th><center><b>Ukupno</b></center></th>
        </tr>
        <asp:Repeater ID="ItemRepeater" runat="server" DataSource='<%# Eval("Products") %>' > 
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <center><img src="/DBImages/<%# Eval("Product.Image") %>.png" class="productImage"/></center>
                        </td>
                        <td style="text-align:right">
                            <center><p><b>Proizvođač: </b><%# Eval("Product.Manufacturer.Name")%></p></center>
                            <center><p><b>Naziv: </b><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ProductID" %></p></center>
                        </td>
                        <td style="text-align:right">
                            <center><p><%# Eval("Qunatity")%></p></center>
                        </td>
                        <td style="text-align:right">
                            <center><p><%# Eval("Product.Price")%></p></center>
                        </td>
                        <td style="text-align:right">
                            <%--<center><p><%# Eval("Qunatity")%></p></center>--%>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
        </table>
        <b style="float: right; font-size:larger; margin-right: 30px;">
            Svega: <%# Eval("Sum")%> RSD
        </b>
    <br />
    <hr />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

My problem is this: How can I display the attributes of the Product object in the inner repeater.

My Product object looks like this:

```
public class Product
{
    [Key]
    public int ProductID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public double Price { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Quantity { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public bool OnSale { get; set; }

    public double SalePrecent { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int Image { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int Stock { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CategoryID")]
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int ManufacturerID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ManufacturerID")]
    public virtual Manufacturer Manufacturer { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you declare your outer repeater you should handle the OnItemDataBound event and within this event Databind your inner repeater

Outer repeater:

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" id="CartRepeater" OnItemDataBound="CartRepeater_ItemDataBound">
...
</asp:Repeater>
```

Code behind:

```
protected void CartRepeater_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
if (e.Item.ItemType != ListItemType.Item && e.Item.ItemType != ListItemType.AlternatingItem) return;

var item = (CartItems) e.Item.DataItem;

var repeater = (Repeater) e.Item.FindControl("ItemRepeater");

repeater.DataSource = item.Products;
repeater.DataBind();
}
```

And your `Eval("Product.SomeProperty")` expressions are not needed. Remove the `Product.` bit from the string, for example:

`<%# Eval("Product.Image") %>` becomes `<%# Eval("Image") %>`

Comment: Cart can have a collection of CartItems, thats tha problem. I need to display the CartItems collection for every Cart, and the Cart can be a collection to.

For example. I need to list all the orders for a day. In that day I can have many orders. Every oreder can have more items and the quantity for those items.

Comment: I tried the both solution, but it says

Unable to cast object of type '<>f__AnonymousType2`5[System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1[BurnFat.CartItems],System.Int32,System.String,System.Double,System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Int32]]' to type 'BurnFat.CartItems'.

Comment: I need still to access the CartItems Product object attributes in the inner repeater.

Comment: Oh ok... so you have multiple Carts on the same page, and within each Cart you have the products? Just to be clear, in your original code what is the type of "items" that you assign to your outer repeater?

Comment: Yes, items is collection of cart objects, cart objcet has a collection of ItemCarts

items are IEnumerable<object> anonymus type, but now I changed it to a new class named AdminCartItems and put there the wanted attributes.

Comment: In that case what I said originally should work - I removed my edit

Answer (score 0):

You're binding your inner repeater to Products:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="ItemRepeater" runat="server" DataSource='<%# Eval("Products") %>' >
```

So each bound DataItem in the inner repeater is a Product.  Therefore instead of:

```
 <center><p><b>Proizvođač: </b><%# Eval("Product.Manufacturer.Name")%></p></center>
```

You should be specifying:

```
 <center><p><b>Proizvođač: </b><%# Eval("Manufacturer.Name")%></p></center>
```

Comment: I did this, I will post answer when the 8 hour passes.

Answer (score 0):

As u can see, I updated the question, so there is now a AdminCartsItem class. The outer repeater gets the datasource fromhere:

```
List<AdminCartItems> items = (from c in context.Carts
                                              where c.Bill.Date == currentDate
                                              select new AdminCartItems
                                              {
                                                  Product = c.Products.Select(x => x.Product),
                                                  BillNo = c.Bill.BillNumber,
                                                  Orderer = c.Bill.Name + ", " + c.Bill.Adress + ", " + c.Bill.PostalCode + " " + c.Bill.Country,
                                                  Sum = c.Products.Sum(x => x.Qunatity * x.Product.Price),
                                                  Pices = (int)c.Products.Select(x => x.Qunatity).FirstOrDefault(),
                                                  Total = (c.Products.Select(x => x.Product.Price)).FirstOrDefault() * (int)c.Products.Select(x => x.Qunatity).FirstOrDefault()
                                              }).ToList();
```

The inner repeater ItemDataBound event look like this:

```
protected void CartRepeaterItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Item.ItemType != ListItemType.Item && e.Item.ItemType != ListItemType.AlternatingItem) return;

            var item = (AdminCartItems)e.Item.DataItem;

            var repeater = (Repeater)e.Item.FindControl("ItemRepeater");

            repeater.DataSource = item.Product;
            repeater.DataBind();
        }
```

The HTML looks now like this:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="CartRepeater" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="CartRepeaterItemDataBound"> 
        <ItemTemplate>
            <p><b>Broj računa: </b><%# Eval("BillNo")%></p>
            <p><b>Naručioc: </b><%# Eval("Orderer")%></p>
            <br />

            <table class="table">
            <tr>
                <th><center><b>Slika</b></center></th>
                <th><center><b>Proizvod</b></center></th>
                <th><center><b>Pakovenje</b></center></th>
                <th><center><b>Cena</b></center></th>
                <th><center><b>Količina</b></center></th>
                <th><center><b>Ukupno</b></center></th>
            </tr>
            <asp:Repeater ID="ItemRepeater" runat="server" > 
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <center><img src="/DBImages/<%# Eval("Image") %>.png" class="productImage"/></center>
                            </td>
                            <td style="text-align:right">
                                <center><p><b>Proizvođač: </b><%# Eval("Manufacturer.Name")%></p></center>
                                <center><p><b>Naziv: </b><%# Eval("Name")%></p></center>
                            </td>
                            <td style="text-align:right">
                                <center><p><%# Eval("Quantity")%></p></center>
                            </td>
                            <td style="text-align:right">
                                <center><p><%# Eval("Price")%></p></center>
                            </td>
                            <td style="text-align:right">
                                <center><p><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.Parent.Parent, "DataItem.Pices")%> </p></center>
                            </td>
                            <td style="text-align:right">
                                <center><p><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.Parent.Parent, "DataItem.Total")%> </p></center>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
            </table>
            <b style="float: right; font-size:larger; margin-right: 30px;">
                Svega: <%# Eval("Sum")%> RSD
            </b>
        <br />
        <hr />
        <hr />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

Hope this will help.